# powershell not exporting

Tags: sql, powershell, csv

hi i am running the following query in powershell:

```
Import-Module Hall.psm1

$Database = 'Report'
$Server = '192.168.1.2'
$Query = 'SELECT all * FROM [Report].[dbo].[TestView]'
$LogLocation = "\\Report\LogFile.csv"
$DynamicYear = (Get-Date).Year
$DynamicMonth = (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName((Get-Date).Month)
$FileDestination = "\\Report\MONTHLY REPORTS\"+$DynamicYear+"\"+$DynamicMonth+"\"
$Outputfilename='TestView-'+(Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')+'.csv'
$LocalCreate = 'C:\Scripts\LocalCreate\'
$FolderPathExtension = "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::"
$CodeDestination = $FolderPathExtension+$FileDestination
$filedest=$LocalCreate+$outputfilename
$Logfile = $FolderPathExtension+$LogLocation

Invoke-sqlcmd -querytimeout 120 -query "
$Query
" -database $database -serverinstance $server |

ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | # Convert to CSV string data without the type metadata
Select-Object -Skip 0 | # Trim header row, leaving only data columns
% {$_ -replace '"',''} | # Remove all quote marks

Set-Content -Path $filedest

(gc $filedest) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | set-content $filedest

if(Test-Path ($filedest)) { 
Move-Item -Path $filedest -Destination $CodeDestination -Force

$LogType = 'INFO'
$LogEntry = "$filedest MovedTo $To"
Write-Log -Message $LogEntry -Level $LogType -Logfile $Logfile
}
```

which works fine without any issue if the query has data.
however, if the query does not have any data it does not create a .csv. how can i get it to create a blank .csv? or .csv with headers only?

Comment: Create a blank file first, this way it will exist regardless of if you have any content to write to it or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `New-Item -ItemType File -Path $filedest` before your `Invoke-SqlCmd` Or `ConvertTo-Csv`